# Storing data from variable length xml files without classes or giant arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, xml

I'm working on a java project with 4000+ xml files. The basic layout is:

```
<Codes>
     <Code>
          <Nums>
               <Num>56</Num>
               <Num>21</Num>
               <Num>4</Num>
          </Nums>
     </Code>
</Codes>
```

These xmls files can have any amount of "num"s, even up to 100,000+. I know that layout of the xml files are weird but I am unable to change the layout because more could be added later.

I need to import these numbers (grouped by xml file). I have already created methods for parsing.  The way of storing them is what is troubling me. I could great a GIANT int array:

int[][] nums = new int[4000][100000]

But this would be extremely memory consuming because some of the xml files have as few as 15 num entries (it raised the mem consumption of the java process by 1gb). The other option I came up with was having an instanced class for every xml file. For numerous reasons I would be unable to do this.

These nums represent to pixel colors that make of photos. The data will not need to be modified, just read by other classes.

Is there another way around this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Without knowing what you want to **do** with these collections we can't possibly advise you.  Back away from the details and explain the real objective.  What do these files represent? What processing do you want to apply to them?

Comment: These nums represent the pixels (color) of pictures (strange I know). They will not need to be modified later. Other classes will need to get the pixels for a certain xml file. They will all be used frequently so it would be best to store them. I have tried just having them read and not permanently assigned to a variable but it slowed down the program to much.

Comment: use a sax parser rather than a dom parser, if changing the xml format or persisting in other way is not an option

Comment: Do you think it would be counterproductive to have a "Pixel" class whos only purpose is to store the data from each xml (instanced?). The reason I was afraid of doing this earlier was it just seemed pointless. In terms changing the parser i'm not so sure it would work. When the program runs it loads all of the xml files into the giant array (the problem I am trying to fix). If I didn't do this and just had the classes load each xml file when it needed it the program would slow down a ton. These files are accessed several times a second from all several different classes.

Comment: The data structure you've shown does not encode the raster row length, so how do you know when a row of pixels is done and the next pixel is on the next row?

Comment: If your issue is that you don't know how big one file can be, just use a `List<List<java.awt.Color>>` where each pixel is encoded as a `Color` instance. This is effectively a dynamic 2d array.  Once one XML file is loaded you can then reduce it to a 'real' 2d array of `Color` to conserve memory.

Comment: Couldn't you create a 2D array with a variable dimension? Like `int[][] nums = new int[4000][]`. Then you can instantiate the second array according to the actual data you have in each file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your doing but you should probably seriously consider using some persistence technology like a database.

You seem to be concerned with memory as you should because loading a bunch of files in memory (4000 with 100k lines of XML) is probably going to waste a lot of memory while also being slow to access. A massive integer array can be fast but you will probably have to load the entire array leading to very slow startup time.

With a durable database you load the xml files once and have fast access after that.

Comment: I did consider this. The problem is the read time. Each of these arrays are accessed all the time. Some are even accessed several times a second. This program is a client so all of the clients would be accessing it too. I fear it would create tons of traffic. I did attempt the instancing method and I got the program down to ~135 mbs which I find acceptable.